# "The focus of this section is on.." vs "The focus of this section is ..."

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I would like to understand the using of the word **focus**. Do I need to use **focus on** or **focus**? Which one is correct?

> The focus of this section is on introducing something.

or

> The focus of this section is introducing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the word *focus* is a noun. If you are not sure about the usage, always check dictionaries. Check the examples. Cambridge ***bolds*** the prepositions that are mandatory to use in almost all words' definitions.

Focus [as in Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/focus) reads:

> - the main or central point of something, especially of attention or interest*

The example following the definite uses *of* **or** *on* depending on the contexts. In your case, it should be used with the preposition *on.*

Comment: "Focus on sth" is a phrasal verb. It says so in the same dictionary entry, you have to scroll further down

Comment: What is a "point"? in "the central point"?  It seems to beg the question.